# iOS Facebook app request dialog always sending frictionless requests

Tags: ios, facebook, apprequests

I am developing a game which uses the Facebook SDK and web dialogs to present friend selector and send app requests.

The problem is this: when I send a request to someone for the first time, the request is sent without showing confirmation dialog.

Can someone suggest what can be cause of such behaviour?

Please find code below.

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [SBJsonWriter new];

NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:kGiftHearts], @"type",
                             @-1, @"gate",
                             nil];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [writer stringWithObject:data], @"data",
                               nil];

[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]
 message:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:STR_GIFT_MESSAGE]
 title: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:STR_GIFT_TITLE]
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         (target->*failure)(target);
     } else {
         (target->*success)(target);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Have you ever sent that user a frictionless request for that app id in the past at any point? Maybe even through a web version of your fb app?

Comment: No, it sends frictionless requests for users to which I didn't sent any messages before.